# Contructor definition: receiving "no argument given"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a derived class and I am receiving this syntax error for each constructor.

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'p' of 'Parent.Parent(Parent)'

This doesn't make any sense to me. This is a constructor definition not a method call I have never see this before on something that isn't a call.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

        public class Parent
        {
            public string Label;

            public Parent(Parent p)
            {
                Label = p.Label;
            }
        }

        public class Child : Parent
        {
            public string Label2;

            public Child(Parent p)
            {
                Label = p.Label;
            }

            public Child(Child c)
            {
                Label = c.Label;
                Label2 = c.Label2;
            }

            public Child(string blah, string blah2)
            {
                Label = blah;
            }
        }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, it would be best to reduce your problem to a `[mcve`] - in this case, a base class with a parameterized constructor (ideally of a common type such as `string`) and a derived class with a single constructor. Show the error message as text rather than an image...

Comment: I did show the error message as text.....

Comment: So you don't need to show it as an image as well. The image doesn't actually add anything other than showing that it's the class name that has the red squiggles - something you could easily have just described.

Comment: I like visuals, to my knowledge there is no rule against it as long as you also provide error messages in text form.

Comment: It's not a "rule" - but I don't think it adds anything, whereas reducing this to a [mcve] *would* definitely improve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
public LabelImage(LabelImage source)
{
    Label = source.Label;
    image = new MagickImage(source.image);
    fileinfo = source.fileinfo;
}
```

Is implicitly this:

```
public LabelImage(LabelImage source) : base()
{
    Label = source.Label;
    image = new MagickImage(source.image);
    fileinfo = source.fileinfo;
}
```

Note the `base()` part, trying to call either a `MyImageAndStuff` parameterless constructor, or one which only has a `params` array parameter, or one with only optional parameters. No such constructor exists, hence the error.

You probably want:

```
public LabelImage(LabelImage source) : base(source)
{
    Label = source.Label;
    image = new MagickImage(source.image);
    fileinfo = source.fileinfo;
}
```

... and similar things for all your other constructors. Either that, or you need to add a parameterless constructor to `MyImageAndStuff`. It does seem very odd that you can't create an instance of `MyImageAndStuff` without *already having* an instance of `MyImageAndStuff` - although I guess `source` could be null.

Comment: @Nabren was correct it was because the base class did not have a default constructor defined. You gave a more detailed answer though so you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because MyImageAndStuff does not have a parameterless constructor or a constructor that can be resolved without any arguments passed to it you need to explicitly call a constructor from MyImageAndStuff in all derived constructors inside of LabelImage. Example:

```
  public LabelImage(LabelImage source)
    : base(source)
```

Comment: Note that the term "default constructor" is usually used in the C# specification when describing a constructor the compiler supplies for you. In this case, you mean "parameterless constructor" - but a constructor with just a `params` array parameter or only optional parameters would be fine too.

Comment: It's still not correct though - if just had `MyImageAndStuff(MyImageAndStuff source = null)` it wouldn't have a parameterless constructor, but it would compile. On the other hand, fixing that would make your answer basically a subset of mine...